# Dockerfile changes are not in Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a Dockerfile that installs java, and sets it as an environment variable $JAVA_VERSION. Everything seems to pass. At the end of the Dockerfile I execute a .sh file that references to the $JAVA_VERSION. It says it cannot find the environment variable. I then bash in to the running container, and I cannot find the installed java, nor the java environment variable.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The Dockerfile would be a nice to have

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you set this environment variable.

You should use the [`ENV` directive](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env) in the dockerfile (otherwise, you need [the option `-e` on `docker run`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494145/6309))

> I then bash in to the running container,

That would be `docker exec -it <yourContainer> path/to/bash`, and you should find what the Dockerfile has built.