# Restarting Apache Inside Docker and Keeping Environment Variables

Tags: docker, env

### Context

I'm [using environment variables with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers) to configure my applications. This way a single built image can serve many different users who will need different configurations.

When developing, I often enter the container and perform a few tweaks before restarting Apache. This could be something like editing the php.ini file to turn on debugging info. However, if I do this, PHP loses access to all of the environment variables that have been set, and the application stops working.

### Question

Is there a way I can restart the Apache server within a docker container, and maintain access to all of the environment variables in PHP that were passed in at deployment with `docker run ... -e foo=bar`?

### Extra Info

The script I use to enter the docker is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash 

EXPECTED_NUM_ARGS=1;

if [ "$#" -ne $EXPECTED_NUM_ARGS ]; then
    # user didn't specify which container ID, assume the latest one
    CONTAINER_ID=`/usr/bin/docker ps -q --no-trunc | /bin/sed -n 1p`
    /usr/bin/docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID env TERM=xterm bash
else
    # enter the container the user specified
    /usr/bin/docker exec -it $1 env TERM=xterm bash
fi
```

In case it matters, I am *not* using Apache as the foreground process of the container, thus I can restart Apache without the container stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [a similar issue on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146688/why-doesnt-apache2-respect-my-envvars-file) it looks like I was restarting Apache incorrectly.

I had been running `service apache2 restart`. If I run `apache2ctl restart` instead, then there is no issue.