# Jenkins Pipeline Step withEnv does not work without BASH

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I've trouble setting an environment variable for a container in an Jenkins pipeline.
It seems, that "withEnv" does not work nicely with machines without bash.

Can you confirm that? I cannot find an official statement ;-)

When I run the following snippet on the Jenkins slave it works.
But when it is executed in a docker container without BASH "$test" isn't set.

```
 withEnv(["test='asd'"]){
      sh 'echo $test'
 }
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables

Comment: Is "test" a groovy variable or a bash variable?

Comment: test should become a bash variable (in the block).

Comment: It is possible that Jenkins node passes variables to sub-shell where is runs docker, but docker does not pass environment variables to its own subshell; try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494145/1388202

Answer (score 14):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe the variable is not set correctly.

Try this:

```
withEnv(["test=asd"]){
      sh "echo \$test"
 }
```

Within a Jenkins pipeline:

```
$var = Groovy parameter
\$var (within a sh closure) = Bash parameter
${var} = also refers to Groovy parameter
```

In order to insert a groovy variable into a bash variable:

```
sh ("VAR=${GROOVY_VAR}")
```

Using a bash variable inside a sh closure:

```
sh (" echo \$BASH_VAR")
```

Comment: In general, I agree. This is the way it should work.
Although, since the initial snippet uses ticks, it should work, too.

But when I select a container with a very limited linux, withEnv doesn't work anymore - the variables are just not set.

Comment: Using Groovy variables can potentially lead to [Injection via Interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation) vulnerabilities, so it's good you've mentioned they're different.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use single quote when using withEnv in Jenkins.

```
withEnv(['test=asd']){
  sh "echo \$test"
```

}

Because, the variable expansion is being done by the Bourne shell, not Jenkins.
(Quoting from documentation)

Find more info here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/