# Should I use user-secrets or environment variables with docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

When using docker with asp.net core for development, should I use user-secrets or environment variables?  I am using the default docker file that Visual Studio 2017 creates when adding a project, which uses microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1 and I believe is a linux image.

How do I set the user-secrets/environment variables in docker so they are set when it launches, but aren't included in the source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment vars are better - https://12factor.net/config

If you run docker using `docker run` use `-e` or `--env-file` option: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

If you run docker using `docker-compose` use `environment` or `env_file` key: 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I'm using a .env file as described here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file, and adding that to .gitignore.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

For *Development* I rely on .net *secret manager tool*:

1. use **dotnet user-secrets** to store secrets on the local computer

```sh
dotnet user-secrets init

dotnet user-secrets set "Movies:ServiceApiKey" "12345"
..
```

See [MS docs: Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=linux#secret-manager).

2. mount the local folder with secrets to Docker container

Example for Docker:

```sh
docker run ^
  -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development ^
  -v %APPDATA%/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro  ^
  company/image:latest
```

Example for docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

..

  net_core_service:
    ..
    environment:
      # should be defined Development-env to allow loading user-secrets located on the local computer.
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ..
    volumes:
      # map the dotnet user-secret folder
      - $APPDATA/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
    ..

..
```

Comment: Doesn't this expose the secrets when inspecting the container?

Comment: @Hazelへいぜる Yes, but that container will only ever exist locally with those values, so not a worry.

Answer (score 7):

For the production purpose, you need to use environment variables, not use-secrets. Secrets exist **ONLY** for safe storage during development by helping prevent sensitive data from being storing in code / checked into source control:

> The Secret Manager tool does not encrypt the stored secrets and should not be treated as a trusted store. It is for development purposes only. The keys and values are stored in a JSON configuration file in the user profile directory.

---

As alternative to environment variables you may consider using "external" key-value storages, like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), etc.

---

Regarding environment variables in docker, SO already has related questions/answers. See [How to pass environment variables to docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30494050/2833802) as example.

Comment: I know how to pass environment variables with the docker command, but how do I do it so that when I hit debug in Visual Studio and launches the docker images, it passes the environment variables?

Comment: Late to the party.  If you are running VS and need to pass environment variables to your container:

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using user-secrets or environment variables, I decided to add another appsettings file called appsettings.secrets.json.  And then in the constructor add the file like the other appsettings files:

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.secrets.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Just be sure to add the appsettings.secrets.json to the .gitignore file so it isn't added to source control.  User-secrets and environment variables can still be used.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea because your secrets are getting copied into your images?

Comment: Storing secrets and credentials in your source code is generally a bad idea - while it makes things easy for developers to get up and running, it leaves you open to that information leaking out onto the internet. Have a look at answers such as https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38371/how-dangerous-is-it-to-store-password-in-plain-text-on-sites-like-github which goes into it in more detail. User secrets or environment variables keep those details local to your computer, and outside of the context of your application's source code.

Comment: You would probably want to use a password manager to securely store those credentials, for those times when you need to set up a new computer or onboard a new developer, of course.