# How to setup Node environment variable in Dockerfile for running node.js application?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-container

Can anyone suggest how can I setup NODE_ENV variable in dockerfile when running a node app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass environment variables to docker containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)

Answer (score 35):

There a two ways, while building the image or when running the container.

**For builds:**

Add to your Dockerfile

```
ENV NODE_ENV=whatEver
```

Or use build arguments if you don't want them to stick during runtime
    Docker build --build-args NODE_ENV whatEver

**When running:**

Run your container with "-e"

```
docker run -e NODE_ENV=whatever mycontainer
```

Comment: Can this be combined (does the runtime setting override the build-time setting)?

Comment: yep it does override the image environment variable