# Set JAVA_HOME for docker in NLTK for Stanford NLP

Tags: python, docker, nltk, stanford-nlp, java-home

I am a beginner in using Docker.
I'm using Docker toolbox for Windows 7 , i built an image for my python web app and everything works fine.

However, for this app, i use nltk module which also needs java and java_home setting to the java file.
When running on my computer, i can mannualy set the java_home, but how to do it in the dockerfile so that it wont get error when running on another machine.
Here is my error :

[image: My Error]

p.s : Answer below

Comment: Quick question: do you really need docker to do NLTK?

Comment: i think yes because i need to deploy the app on my company server which will using the method of pulling image from dockerhub

Comment: Interesting... If you would like to, please explain the requirements and ideal situation if NLTK is to host self-contained docker images on this issue: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/542

Answer (score 2):

When you are running a container you have the option of passing in environment variables that will be set in your container using the `-e` flag. This answer explains environment variables nicely: [How do I pass environment variables to Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)

`docker container run -e JAVA_HOME='/path/to/java' <your image>`

Make sure your image actually contains Java as well. You might want to look at something like the `openjdk:8` image on docker hub.

It sounds like you need a docker file to build your image. Have a look at the `ENV` command documented here to set the `JAVA_HOME` var: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env and then build your image with `docker build /path/to/Dockerfile`

I see you've already tried that and didn't have much luck.. run the container and instead of running your application process just run a bash script along the lines of `echo $JAVA_HOME` so you can at least verify that part is working.

Also make sure you copy in whatever files/binaries needed to the appropriate directories within the image in the docker file as noted below.

Comment: He could even just include a "bootstrap" script in his Docker build that calls his python app and sets the environment variable

Comment: well the problem is i think i am not running the container. I just push it to dockerhub and use another app to pull the docker image back and deploy it to the company server. Therefore,  i just can only modify the image before building it so I am seeking for a way allowing me to auto set java_home for the images

Comment: @NickBrady even with the variable without mounting the actual binaries and the Stanford nlp directories onto docker, the code won't be able to access any of those resources.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the way to install the java for dockerfile , it is use the java install commandline of ubuntu image.
Below is the docker file . Thanks for your reading.

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```