# How do I serve static files from Docker in an environment-agnostic way?

Tags: docker, frontend

I've been trying to set up a Docker environment, where the frontend (Angular/TypeScript in our case) is built in the Docker file and then served through Nginx.

We want to keep the Docker images environment-agnostic (so we can change our environment without having to rebuild the images). This means we can't build the code with environment variables. So far the options we see are:

- inject the values on serving the code (probably some performance impact, don't know any neat way of doing this)
- still build separate images (& drop our requirement)
- have all environments compiled into the code with `environment.<env>.ts` files (not really agnostic images, just between a static set of environments)

Is there any recommended method of doing this? Am I missing something? I feel like this should be a solved problem, but I can't find anything on how to do this "properly".

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What registry?

Comment: what do you mean by agnostic way?

Comment: You need to inject the values somewhere. What would your ideal point be?

Comment: @DmitriiG. I've edited the post, hopefully that clarifies a little bit what I'm looking for. We want to be able to change the environment without having to change the code.

Comment: @Aankhen this is my question: the "ideal" method is to have the environment be read during runtime, but since we're serving static files to only way to do that is to inject them in _during_ serving, which doesn't seem like a very robust solution.

Comment: I’m confused because it sounds like you have a solution but you (rightly) don’t want to use it since it isn’t a good idea. What’s the reason for wanting to delay the environment configuration until runtime, and what exactly constitutes the environment, in your eyes? It may be that we’re talking about different things.

Comment: @Aankhen the environment (for example, the domain name, the url for the backend APIs; stored in environment variables) would have to be somehow injected into the code, after starting the Docker container. The code has to be served _with_ embedded environment values. Injecting _after_ start means either we have some script run after starting the container that replaces all occurrences of `ENVIRONMENT_VAR` with the value of that variable, or we do it through nginx (replacing them before sending the files to the client).

Comment: Okay. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: Are you trying to do this https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8838 ?

Comment: A potential answer is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53656839/2249614). They inject the env-specific values during container start, so no performance impact once the container is running.