# How to make a single React Docker build/image to run through all environments?

Tags: reactjs, docker, continuous-integration, environment-variables

i'm trying to deploy a React application in a single Docker container able to run through dev, preprod and prod on an OpenShift platform on which i can only push tagged docker images. In order to do this i have:

- a React application generated with create-react-app hosted on Github
- a Dockerfile at project root containing the docker build/run process
- a .gitlab-ci.yml file containing the continuous integration checks and deploy methods
- an accessible OpenShift platform

**What i can do:**

I can easily generate a production build '/build' that will be added in the docker image build phase and will run with a production context or i can build at run start (but just writing it feels bad).

**The problem:**

This generated image isn't able to run through all environment, and i don't want to have a specific build for each environment.

**What i want:**

I want to be able to generate a single docker image that will run through all environments without having to install dependencies or build when only RUN is needed.

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.5-alpine
RUN addgroup --system app \
    && adduser --uid 1001 --system --ingroup app app \
    && rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
    && apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm \
    && mkdir /apptmp
COPY . /apptmp
RUN chmod 777 /apptmp
COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY config/buildWithEnv.sh .

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R app:app /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R app:app /var/cache/nginx && \
  chown -R app:app /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001
CMD sh buildWithEnv.sh
```

And here is the script buildWithEnv.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "===> Changin directory: /apptmp ..."
cd /apptmp

echo "===> Installing dependencies: npm install ..."
npm install

echo "===> Building application: npm run build ..."
npm run build

echo "===> Copying to exposed html folder ... "
rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
cp -r build/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

echo "===> Launching http server ... "
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: No craftman for this ?

Comment: Where is the environment specific part in your buildWithEnv.sh / What is the environment specific part in your docker-image? Anyhow, the content of your `buildWithEnv.sh` script should definitely be moved into the Dockerfile except the last line. `npm install`, `npm run build` should be part of the docker-build and not run on container startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way.

## Build application

The first step is to make a static build of your application, environment agnostic. (Actually for my situation this is done by the CI so i directly retrieve the static build in Docker build part)

## Create Nginx conf

In your project, create a file holding the default configuration for nginx, plus the reverse proxy configuration your need, and fill the `proxy_pass` with values easily and uniquely replacable.

```
server {
  gzip on;
  gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/json;
  gzip_vary on;
  listen 8080;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header x-clientapikey REACT_APP_BAMBOO_API_KEY;
    proxy_pass REACT_APP_SERVICE_BACK_URL;
  }
  location /auth {
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic REACT_APP_AUTHENTIFICATION_AUTHORIZATION";
    proxy_pass REACT_APP_SERVICE_AUTH_URL;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

## Openshift configuration

In your OC application, go to the "environment" tab, and add all the environnement variables you will use in your nginx conf.

## Dockerfile build

In the dockerfile build part, move your build to its correct position into nginx html folder, and handle your configuration files, including nginx.

```
FROM nginx:1.15.5-alpine
RUN addgroup --system app \
  && adduser --uid 1001 --system --ingroup app app \
  && rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
  && apk --update add sed
COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN chmod 777 -R /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY config/nginxSetup.sh .

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R app:app /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R app:app /var/cache/nginx && \
  chown -R app:app /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001
CMD sh nginxSetup.sh
```

## Dockerfile run

In the dockerfile run part (CMD), just use the command line tool `sed` in order to replace paths in your nginx reverse proxy configuration.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed -i "s|REACT_APP_SERVICE_BACK_URL|${REACT_APP_SERVICE_BACK_URL}|g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
sed -i "s|REACT_APP_SERVICE_AUTH_URL|${REACT_APP_SERVICE_AUTH_URL}|g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
sed -i "s|REACT_APP_BAMBOO_API_KEY|${REACT_APP_BAMBOO_API_KEY}|g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
sed -i "s|REACT_APP_AUTHENTIFICATION_AUTHORIZATION|${REACT_APP_AUTHENTIFICATION_AUTHORIZATION}|g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
echo "===> Launching http server ... "
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

And here you are.

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach is described on this [blog-post](https://blog.manifold.co/building-a-production-grade-container-for-your-static-javascript-application-b2b2eff83fbd)

Basically: You use placeholders for all environment specific parts in your static resources. Then you configure nginx' [`sub_filter`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) to replace those at runtime with the environment specific values.