# Error when I start helloWorld.java in docker

Tags: java, docker

I try create helloWorld application on hava and start it in docker on windows.

1. I write application:

   ```
   public class HelloWorld {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Start... ");
           System.out.println("Hello Pavel!");
       }
   }
   ```
2. I create Docker file:

   ```
   FROM java:8
   ADD HelloWorld.java .
   RUN javac HelloWorld.java
   CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
   ```
3. Bouth files I put to `java-application` folder:

   ```
   -java-application
   -HelloWorld.java
   -Dockerfile
   ```
4. I try build it:

> ```
> Pavel\java-application>docker build -t java-application .
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
> Step 1/4 : FROM java:8
>  ---> d23bdf5b1b1b
> Step 2/4 : ADD HelloWorld.java .
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> d4e0c540b57b
> Step 3/4 : RUN javac HelloWorld.java
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 5f5204f28710
> Step 4/4 : CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 53ebab34502c
> Successfully built 53ebab34502c
> Successfully tagged java-application:latest
> SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
> ```

I show all images:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
java-application    latest              53ebab34502c        2 minutes ago       643MB
hello-world         latest              4ab4c602aa5e        8 days ago          1.84kB
ubuntu              latest              cd6d8154f1e1        9 days ago          84.1MB
nginx               latest              06144b287844        10 days ago         109MB
java                8                   d23bdf5b1b1b        20 months ago       643MB
```

5. I try start application:

   C:\Pavel\java-application>docker run java-application
   Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

**EDDIT**

I change dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD HelloPavel.java .
RUN javac HelloPavel.java
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "HelloPavel"]
```

I have

```
hello-pavel         latest              c817bd40d62c        25 seconds ago      624MB
```

I start:

```
C:\Pavel\hello-pavel>docker run hello-pavel:latest
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloPavel
```

Comment: Please switch from [java](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) image to [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) image as it is marked as deprecated. Furthermore, you should use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` as this is the right way to create executable images according to [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).

Comment: I use this tutorial https://www.tutorialkart.com/docker/docker-Java-application-example/

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, the class Helloworld is not in your java classpath inside docker. Add it with

```
java -cp . HelloPavel
```

When you first changed your directory to where your compiled class is.

Comment: Where do I add this line? Run it in the console, add it to the dockerfile?

Comment: Check this: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/ and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: it's still hard to understand

Comment: So there are two choices. The problem is you do not have the class you call in your classpath inside docker. Choice one is to add the classpath as part of your java-command. For that purpose is the -cp parameter, and the other possibility is to add the path to your classpath as part of the environment inside docker.  Because docker is normally used to run a single program, both ways to do it are good. But first try to run it outside docker, study the classpath if it runs, and see what is different inside docker. You learn most if you can figure it out without further help. Success