# PHP on Docker - pass a variable to container by docker run CLI command

Tags: php, docker, variables, environment-variables

There is a docker php container run by **docker run** command.

1.How to pass by using docker run command a variable to the php container?

2.How to read value of the passed variable from php script in that container?

Context: PHP script inside a docker container connects to a database that is located on an another container. I need to run several php containers that connect to differently named database containers.

I can't have hardcoded database container name inside the php script and need to pass database conatainer name dynamically when I use docker run to startup php containers.

Comment: You can set environment variables  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an environment variable using the `-e DB_NAME='hostname'` as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494145/2940966.

The environment variable can be  accessed from the PHP script as follows.

```
echo 'The DB Name is ' .$_ENV["DB_NAME"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me on `Ubuntu 22.04` with `PHP 8.1`, however using the same env variable in docker run:

```
-e DB_NAME='hostname'
```

and in PHP:

```
echo "My DB name is ".getenv('DB_NAME').".\n";
```

... did work correctly.