# how to access env variables from docker compose file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a two services in docker compose 1. an application and 2. db service (can be Mysql or Postgres). Depending upon environment variables set in compose file for db services, I need create DATABASE_URI for sqlalchemy engine. How do I access these ENV in app docker container?

I am trying to access env set inside docker-compose file and not Dockerfile.

Below is how my Docker-compose file looks

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myapp:
    image: ${TAG:-myapp}
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"


  docker_postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing it in the same way you'd access any other environment variable from Python?

Comment: Yes, but gets nothing.

Comment: Then please give a [mcve]. For what it's worth, the project I'm currently working on passes env vars from my environment, through the compose file, into the container, and into the code (mostly JS, but we do have some Python) just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass environment variables to Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)

Comment: I want to excess env vars set for db (for.eg postgres db) in compose file inside my app container to construct database_uri.

Comment: Yes, that part is clear. What's unclear is how you're currently attempting to *actually implement that*. [This](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) is working fine for me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is how I have implemented too.

Comment: Is it possible to show the docker-compose file. At least then we can see what you have done.

Comment: So **give a [mcve]**. `docker-compose`, `Dockerfile`, `some.py` - how is this actually set up?

Comment: You appear to not actually be setting `DATABASE_URI`, or any other environment variable, for `myapp`. So why did you think it *would* be set?

Comment: I am planning to construct database_uri using all env set under compose file. For eg `postgresql://{POSTGRES_USER}:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@{POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/{POSTGRES_DB}`

Comment: But **you haven't set any of those**. You clearly know how to set them, because you're doing it for the `docker_postgres` service, so why don't you do the same thing for `myapp`? I don't understand why you think there's a *problem* here, you just haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment variables for your postgres database if you want to build your own database_uri.

```
environment:
POSTGRES_DB: dev
POSTGRES_USER: username
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw
```

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe You mean to say I can do something like this?

````
services:
  myapp:
    image: ${TAG:-myapp}
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_HOST=docker_postgres
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"


  docker_postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"```
````