# VSCode Remote Container - extensions not installing on dev container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am having trouble getting extensions installed in the dev container using "Remote - Containers". I do not know if it's a bug, incorrect configuration on my end, or intended behaviour. Down below is my current configuration, both files are located in the root folder of the project.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  api:
    image: node:12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT}:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    working_dir: /usr/app
    command: bash -c "yarn && yarn dev"
```

.devcontainer.json

```json
{
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "api",
    "workspaceFolder": "/usr/app",
    "extensions": [
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        "formulahendry.auto-rename-tag",
        "coenraads.bracket-pair-colorizer-2",
        "kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode",
        "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin",
        "visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode"
    ]
}
```

The list of extensions listed in the `.devontainer.json` are the ones I want to have installed in the dev container. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It worked when I set it up on a different computer. It probably was an issue with caching or similar.

Answer (score 12):

According to [the Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_using-an-image-or-dockerfile), the two files need to be located in a *directory* `.devcontainer` in the workspace root.

I still had issues installing the extensions while working from behind a corporate proxy. The solution was to give the container access to the proxy server:

If you use an `authenticating` proxy like Cntlm on your local machine, configure it to listen on `172.17.0.1` (the Docker interface). Then define the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables for the container. For example, in `devcontainer.json`:

```
"containerEnv": { 
  "http_proxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128",
  "https_proxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128"
}
```

Or in `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  devcontainer:
    environment:
      http_proxy: http://172.17.0.1:3128
      https_proxy: http://172.17.0.1:3128
```

Or configure `docker-compose.yaml` to make the container use the host network:

```yaml
services:
  devcontainer:
    network_mode: host
```

Then you can just pass the same proxy variables into the container as used on the host. For example, in the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  devcontainer:
    environment:
      http_proxy: $http_proxy
      https_proxy: $https_proxy
```

If you are not using a local, but rather a remote proxy inside of your network, you can do the latter regardless of the container's network configuration (host or default).

Comment: This is a really nice first post. Thank you for putting so much detail into it.

Comment: Was going around in circles and needed to be spoonfed that 172.17.0.1 was a Docker-relevant interface to believe this approach was worth trying. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

I also have issues installing the extensions while working from behind a corporate proxy. The solution was to give the container access to the proxy server and set HTTP proxy strict SSL:

```
"settings": {
    "http.proxy": "(your_proxy_host:port)",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is only applicable if your network environment requires the use of a proxy server.*

According to ["Known limitations"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_known-limitations) of "Developing inside a Container"...

> Local proxy settings are not reused inside the container, which can prevent extensions from working unless the appropriate proxy information is configured (for example global HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables with the appropriate proxy information).

I was able to set the proxy environment variables by appending to `runArgs` in 'devcontainer.json': `"--net=host", "--env=https_proxy=(your_proxy_host:port)"`.

---

Alternatively, if host-access is not required for the proxy, you can just append to '.devcontainer/Dockerfile':

```
ENV https_proxy=(your_proxy_host:port)
```

---

*Enabling proxy access in this way may also be necessary for network access from your application (not just for vscode extensions).*

See also: [How do I pass environment variables to Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71862578/86967)