# Pass environment variables from docker-compose to vue app with nginx

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose

I want to dockerize my vuejs app and to pass it environment variables from the docker-compose file.

I suspect the app gets the environment variables only at the build stage, so it does not get the environment variables from the docker-compose.

vue app:

```
process.env.FIRST_ENV_VAR
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk add --update nginx nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/vue-single-page-app
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

COPY nginx_config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx_config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /tmp/nginx/vue-single-page-app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN cp -r dist/* /var/www/html

RUN chown nginx:nginx /var/www/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  app:
    image: myRegistry/myProject:tag
    restart: always
    environment:
      - FIRST_ENV_VAR="first environment variable"
      - SECOND_ENV_VAR="first environment variable"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Is there any way to pass environment variables to a web application after the build stage?

Comment: you are already pass the ENV in your run stage , for build stage you need to use `Build ARGs` the problem must be somehting else ...

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: I know how to pass environment variables to the container, but once the app has been built it can't get any environment variable anymore

Comment: I couldn't find how to solve this problem for Vue. But I found for Angluar. We can take the idea from there and use in Vue: https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/
Briefly: they have an env.js file that is not part of obfuscated code after build (it served as asset). So it can be replaced by mounted env.js right in environment.

Answer (score 2):

In vue js apps you need to pass the env variables as VUE_APP_
so in your case it should be VUE_APP_FIRST_ENV_VAR

Comment: This is irrelevant, as it will solve nothing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this https://medium.com/@rakhayyat/vuejs-on-docker-environment-specific-settings-daf2de660b9, I have made a silly npm package that help to acomplish what you want.

Go to https://github.com/juanise/jvjr-docker-env and take a look to README file.

Basically just run `npm install jvjr-docker-env`. A new Dockerfile, entrypoint and json file will be added to your project.

Probably you will need to modify some directory and/or file name in Dockerfile in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The value of `FIRST_ENV_VAR` inside docker will be set to the value of `FIRST_ENV_VAR_ON_HOST` on your host system.

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  app:
    image: myRegistry/myProject:tag
    restart: always
    environment:
      - FIRST_ENV_VAR=$FIRST_ENV_VAR_ON_HOST
      - SECOND_ENV_VAR=$SECOND_ENV_VAR_ON_HOST
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: He knows how to pass environment variables to the container, but once the app has been built it can't get any environment variable anymore which is normal because the SPA is already built

Answer (score -3):

As you can see in the docker docs [docker-compose reference envs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)
the defined environment values are always available in the container, not only at build stage.

You can check this by change the CMD to execute the command "env" to display all environments in your container.

If your application is not getting the actual values of the env variables it should be anything else related with your app

Comment: He knows how to pass environment variables to the container, but once the app has been built it can't get any environment variable anymore which is normal because the SPA is already built