# docker-compose.yml won't read environment variable for hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, centos7

I haven't posted on SO in a long while, I hope I am not breaking any rules.

I have an environment variable in my `~/.bash_profile` exported as below and I made sure to run `source ~/.bash_profile`:

```
export HOSTNAME=some-name
```

And this is how my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
    someservice:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        image: ...
        container_name: ...
        restart: unless-stopped
        hostname: "someservice.${HOSTNAME:?Error: env var HOSTNAME is not defined or is empty}"
        ...
```

If I run `docker-compose up -d`, I will get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "hostname" option in service "some-service":
 "someservice.${HOSTNAME:?Error: env var HOSTNAME is not defined or is empty}"
```

If I replace `HOSTNAME` above with `some-name`, I will get the following error:

```
Starting someservice ... error

ERROR: for someservice  Cannot start service: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: 
container init caused \"sethostname: invalid argument\"": unknown

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Any idea why I am getting the error and how to troubleshoot and/or fix it? Thank you so much!

Edit1: Fixed typo in my `export`

Edit2: This might help with troubleshooting: Removing the `ERROR` part from the yaml file fixed the issue. So, in my `docker-compose.yml` I just have:

```
...
   hostname: "someservice.${HOSTNAME} 
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass environment variables to Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)

Comment: Setting `hostname:` for a container has almost no perceivable effect and you can usually delete this setting.

Answer (score 2):

To expose an environment value we use `=` not `:`, change your bash profile to `export HOSTNAME=some-name`

According to the documentation, other extended shell-style features, such as `${VARIABLE/foo/bar}`, are not supported. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/. You might need to only use `"${HOSTNAME:?Error: env var HOSTNAME is not defined or is empty}"` without `someservice.`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately, I mistyped my question. I actually have `export HOSTNAME=some-name`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you set the version of your compose file to '2.1'? This is a diagnostic check to confirm the documentation says what I think it does, so if you have to comment/change other lines to avoid using 3.x features that's ok for now.

The compose file documentation indicates that :? expansion works for compose files version 2.1, and I'm wondering if that was one of the things that didn't get ported over to version 3 compose files (there are a few things like that)