# Run shell command while setting ENV in dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, export

Inside my dockerfile:

```
ENV MY_ENCODED_VALUE="bXkgbmFtZSBpcyByYWtpYgo="

ENV MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(echo $MY_ENCODED_VALUE | base64 -d)
```

in the second line, i want to decode the encoded value and put the decoded value into my environment variable.

---

But i am getting the following error

`Error response from daemon: failed to parse dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "$MY_ENCODED_VALUE". Must be of the form: name=value`

---

What does it even mean? What's supposed to be the right syntax here?

Comment: Is your "MY_ENCODED_VALUE" static. I mean, for each time you build new image, are you willing to change this value or let it be same?

Comment: it will stay same

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: @Rakib: Do you need it only when doing the build or later as well?

Comment: Hi @Technext  @AndyWong i only need it during the build process. I will not need it in the running container. So i am not looking to set env in `docker run`.  For now, i am just not able to make it work because of the syntax inside dockerfile.

Comment: @Rakib: Check updated answer.

Comment: Given that specific base64-encoded value, you can include the decoded string in an `ENV` statement directly.  In the more general case, this isn't something you can set directly in the Dockerfile; the linked question has the typical workarounds.

Comment: This specific base64-encoded value is just for example. Consider it a very long encoded string that is coming from some other source in our setup.

Comment: in that case, can we conclude that it's not possible to interpolate shell commands on a `ENV` step in dockerfile? That an `ENV` step can only accept simple `key=value` format for setting it in a dockerfile?

Comment: i understand passing in docker-run is an option. Just wanna make sure we understand that interpolation is not possile in `ENV` step in a dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned that you need to use the variable during build time only, this should do the job:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
ENV MY_ENCODED_VALUE "bXkgbmFtZSBpcyByYWtpYgo="
RUN echo $MY_ENCODED_VALUE | base64 -d > /root/temp
RUN MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(cat /root/temp); echo "Output: $MY_DECODED_VALUE"
```

Output:

```
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/4 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> bcfeabd22749
Step 2/4 : ENV MY_ENCODED_VALUE "bXkgbmFtZSBpcyByYWtpYgo="
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 81084f4be2e4
Step 3/4 : RUN echo $MY_ENCODED_VALUE | base64 -d > /root/temp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8ad3a100746
Step 4/4 : RUN MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(cat /root/temp); echo "Output: $MY_DECODED_VALUE"
 ---> Running in c9c41b92dee0
Output: my name is rakib
Removing intermediate container c9c41b92dee0
 ---> acfcd422a8ed
Successfully built acfcd422a8ed
Successfully tagged testing:latest
```

Note:

1) The `RUN` instruction in the last line of my `Dockerfile` is for the latter part i.e., the `echo` command. Assigning variable [`MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(cat /root/temp)`] just before the `echo` command ensures that the variable gets set in the same layer where you want to consume it.

2) The way i have used variable assignment, it will not behave as you would expect from an `ENV` instruction i.e., it will not be available for use across layers. If you want to consume the variable in multiple layers, then you will have to use `RUN MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(cat /root/temp); <your-command-that-uses-the-variable>`, wherever applicable. Not an elegant one but that's how it works with my solution.

Comment: This won't work. It will not execute the command. It will set environment variables as raw string: `MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(echo bXkgbmFtZSBpcyByYWtpYgo= | base64 -d)` and `MY_ENCODED_VALUE=bXkgbmFtZSBpcyByYWtpYgo=`

Comment: @kapilKhandelwal is right. It sets the whole raw string

Comment: @Technext you have given the updated solution using `RUN`. But my post was using `ENV`. Is it not possible to do this using `ENV` ? My setup requires ENV.

Comment: The `RUN` instruction in that line is actually for the latter part i.e., the `echo` command. We are just ensuring that the variable gets set in the _same_ layer where you want to consume it.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't serve the purpose.  We can't use that value anywhere else when a container is spun up.

Comment: Are you using the variable in multiple places? If that's the case, then you will have to use `RUN MY_DECODED_VALUE=$(cat /root/temp); <your-command-that-uses-the-var>`, wherever applicable. I know it's not an elegant solution if you need to use the variable's value in _multiple_ layers but that's how it works with my solution.

Comment: in that case, can we conclude that it's not possible to interpolate shell commands on a ENV step in dockerfile? That an ENV step can only accept simple key=value format for setting it in a dockerfile?

Comment: i understand passing in docker-run is an option. Just wanna make sure we understand that interpolation is not possile in ENV step in a dockerfile