# How to pass command line argument as env variable in docker run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image `bcgovimages/aries-cloudagent:py36-1.14-1_0.5.1` and to run it I gave the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5001:5000 -p 10001:10000 --name postgrearies1 bcgovimages/aries-cloudagent:py36-1.14-1_0.5.1 start -it http 0.0.0.0 10000 -ot http --admin 0.0.0.0 5000 --admin-insecure-mode --seed 10000000000000000000111111111110 --wallet-type indy --log-level debug --storage-type indy --wallet-storage-type postgres_storage --wallet-name test2 --wallet-storage-config "{\"url\":\"xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5432\",\"wallet_scheme\":\"DatabasePerWallet\"}" --wallet-storage-creds "{\"account\":\"xxx\",\"password\":\"xxxx\",\"admin_account\":\"postgres\",\"admin_password\":\"xxxxx\"}"
```

I want to pass `--wallet-storage-config` and `--wallet-storage-creds` as environment variables. How can I create a new image from `bcgovimages/aries-cloudagent:py36-1.14-1_0.5.1` which will take `--wallet-storage-config` and --`wallet-storage-creds` as environment variables instead of a command-line argument?

Comment: Use the `-e` flag. Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers). Easily found in the Docker docs also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${...}` in your `Dockerfile`. Use `-e` for describing environment variables for `docker run` operation.

Dockerfile

```
FROM bcgovimages/aries-cloudagent:py36-1.14-1_0.5.1 

ENTRYPOINT start -it http 0.0.0.0 10000 -ot http --admin 0.0.0.0 5000 --admin-insecure-mode --seed 10000000000000000000111111111110 --wallet-type indy --log-level debug --storage-type indy --wallet-storage-type postgres_storage --wallet-name test2 --wallet-storage-config ${WALLET_STORAGE_CONFIG} --wallet-storage-creds ${WALLET_STORAGE_CREDS}
```

Shell

```sh
docker run -d -p 5001:5000 -p 10001:10000 -e WALLET_STORAGE_CONFIG="{\"url\":\"xx.xx.xxx.xxx:5432\",\"wallet_scheme\":\"DatabasePerWallet\"}" -e WALLET_STORAGE_CREDS="{\"account\":\"xxx\",\"password\":\"xxxx\",\"admin_account\":\"postgres\",\"admin_password\":\"xxxxx\"}" --name postgrearies1
```