# ORACLE_HOME environment variable for ORACLE from docker

Tags: windows, oracle, docker, environment-variables

I have oracle which I installed via docker-compose:

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  oracle:
    image: quay.io/maksymbilenko/oracle-xe-11g
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
      - 7080:8080
```

I have to create my ORACLE_HOME environment variable: ORACLE_HOME = Directory path (Example D:\oracle)

Add to the path variable:%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;

Add the tnsnames.ora file to the folder of the installed oracle client /network/admin.

Where can i find all this in Windows 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass environment variables to Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)