# How to use environment variable in Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, docker

I am just experimenting with configuring Dockerfile-

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN echo VERSION_TAG="latest" >> /etc/environment

RUN cat /etc/environment

CMD echo $VERSION_TAG
```

I built the image using (I was in the req directory) -

```
docker build -t temp/testing:latest .
```

Ran it using-

```
docker run temp/testing:latest
```

Expected output-

```
latest
```

Actual Output-

While building the image, the output of `cat /etc/environment`

```
Step 4/5 : RUN cat /etc/environment
 ---> Running in 4grdc7b5165a
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
VERSION_TAG=latest
```

It is present inside env variables, still, its value is not being printed, any help will be appreciated.

Note - I want to do it without using 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: Any hints will be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you do not want to use the ENV command?

Comment: Learning purposes, still solutions with env variables are welcome.

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: I am able to run this by `ENV VERSION_TAG=latest` but not while explicitly setting it, I need to know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know the reason.

Docker just `exec()` the command `ENTRYPOINT`+`CMD` with nothing in between.

`pam` is not loaded, so `pam_env.so` is not loaded, so `/etc/environment` is not read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you point to the resource stating this?

Comment: ? to which part?

Comment: CMD does not run a login session

Comment: There is no resource that something does _not_ happen, usually resources state what happens. It just doesn't run a login session, it's nowhere specified that it does, ergo it doesn't.

Comment: How do you know then? (Not doubting you, just out of curiosity)

Comment: because you don't have to input a password, for example. Because it just `exec()`utes `CMD` inside the environment, there is nothing in between.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The intention is to use `ENV` for this, but you can set extra parameters on the command line at `docker run` [with `-e`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494145/4541045)

```sh
docker run -it -e VERSION='latest' -e NAME='abcd' ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

Alternatively, you can provide a file with each variable per-line

```sh
docker run -it --env-file ./my_env ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

You can also do a [volume mount with `-v`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), which can smuggle further information and entire paths into the container, including information useful to whatever application you run within it (the intent of Docker containers is normally to run a single application within a known environment)

---

However, *if you're trying to determine if the container is running the latest version of its own tag*, this will be problematic
Specifically, the tag may change, but your explicit setting of it won't! .. for such a case, you should consider something else, such as having an outside process which replaces the running container with a new one when the tag changes (so you can assume what's running is always `latest`) or at some frequency (perhaps every day in the morning)