# How can I create multiple images of the same application in Docker with Multiple dynamic Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, activerecord

I am using rails 5.1.0

I want to create multiple images of the same application,
The domain and database of each image will be different,

Example for image_1

- Domain example.app.com
- Database - example_production

Example for image_2

- Domain example1.app.com
- Database - example1_production

Example for image_3

- Domain example3.app.com
- Database - example3_production

#application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: "#{request.base_url}_production", reading: "#{request.base_url}_production" }
end
```

## syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2

```
FROM ruby:2.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image:
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/app
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/shared
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/shared/tmp/sockets
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/shared/tmp/pids

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT/app

# Setting env up
ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
ENV RACK_ENV='production'

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Adding project files
COPY . .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 9292

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: It sounds like you can do that with a single image where you configure it for different domains and databases using environment variables.

Comment: Yes, with the same image and same environment, manage multiple databases according to multiple domains.

Comment: This is really a docker question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: @kwerle I disagree. The solution is a Docker solution. The question isn't.

Comment: Docker Compose, perhaps?

Comment: I have currently deployed the same application on 5 servers for 5 clients, 5 clients have different servers, 5 clients have different domains, and 5 clients have separate databases, now want to deploy them on the same server for 5 clients. 

Note: 5 Client's database will be different and the domain will also be different

Please someone help me, how do I deploy with Docker?

Comment: Again, this is really a docker question.  Also see
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name

Which you would do for each of the 5 instances along with other environment variables to set things up.