# For springboot application, it is good idea to store client_secret in application.yml?

Tags: security, oauth

I am new to backend and from tutorial I read online. It seems like people recommend to do this in application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>
            client-secret: <YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>
            scope: openid,profile,email
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

Is storing client-secret here safe? Or are there any other preferred option?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not safe.

You should put a dummy value and override it when launching the app, using one of the many Spring Boot properties overriding options (`-Dspring.security.oauth2.client.registraion.google.client-secret="change-me"` command line argument, `SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` environment variables, ...)

Comment: If I am using docker. What should I do in this case? Because I assume I can't put the client_secret inside the docker yaml file right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Answer (score 2):

No it is not at all secure , secrets are sensitive and confidential information  , ideally you should do a full risk assessment of your runtime and then take the decision on where exactly you store your secret. In this case assuming that you store it in some vault along with other sensitive information for the application , as the process is launched the environment variables are populated via another script and your spring boot app reads the values from the environment variable itself , something like this will work for you.

```
spring:
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        google:
          client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
          client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
          scope: openid,profile,email
    resourceserver:
      jwt:
        issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
        jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

Also the actual value should be part of the two environment variables GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID & GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any recommendation on what type of vault I could use?

Comment: Best in my opinion would be , The HashiCorp vault as it has an enterprise version as well as an open source version but it all depends on your deployment scenarios ..