# Docker won't let me set environment variables for Jupyter Lab

Tags: docker, jupyter-lab

I'm creating a course that will require students to run some software called PyStan. It turns out that this is [partially supported on Windows](https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html).

Someone gave me an idea to use Docker so that students wouldn't have any issue getting the software they need to do assignments. The end goal is that students can do very little to get Jupyter Lab up and running on their own machines, with as little effort as possible.

I tried writing the following to be run with `sudo docker compose up`

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubuntu_anaconda:
    image: continuumio/anaconda3:latest
    container_name: ubuntu_anaconda
    environment:
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=my_secret_token  # Set your desired token here
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"  # Expose Jupyter Lab port
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data  # Add this line if you want to mount a local directory to the container
    command: /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge pystan && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=${JUPYTER_TOKEN}"
```

However, the first line of the output warns me that

```
WARN[0000] The "JUPYTER_TOKEN" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I am using Docker version 25.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have mentioned that the `JUPYTER_TOKEN` variable isn't being defined, but to clarify why, it's because the `${...}` variables in the compose file are expanded by compose when parsing the yaml file, while the `environment` section is used to define the variable inside of the container. To skip expanding the variable in compose and let bash in the container expand it, you need to escape the variable with a second `$`:

```
    command: /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge pystan && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=$${JUPYTER_TOKEN}"
```

To have compose expand the variable without escaping it or running a shell in the container, you can define the variable in your shell before running `docker compose`, e.g.:

```bash
JUPYTER_TOKEN=my_secret_token docker compose up
```

or you can use the `.env` file that compose processes before parsing the yaml file for its own variables. You can change this file with the `--env-file` option, e.g.:

```bash
docker compose --env-file .secrets up
```

Answer (score 2):

The JUPYTER_TOKEN variable not being set in your Docker Compose
file, you can either explicitly define its value or remove it if not
needed. If setting a token, replace `my_secret_token` with your
desired token. After updating the file, running `sudo docker-compose up` again should eliminate the warning.

2.Using .env file:

- Create a `.env` file in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml`.
- Define variables in the `.env` file (e.g JUPYTER_TOKEN=my_secret_token # Set your desired token ).
- In `docker-compose.yml`, reference these variables using ${VARIABLE_NAME}
  syntax. Docker compose automatically reads variables from the .env file in the current directory.

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubuntu_anaconda:
    image: continuumio/anaconda3:latest
    container_name: ubuntu_anaconda
    environment:
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=${my_secret_token}
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"  # Expose Jupyter Lab port
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data  # Add this line if you want to mount a local directory to the container
    command: /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge pystan && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=${JUPYTER_TOKEN}"
```

3. you can checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers?rq=2)

Comment: If I want to continue to specify it in this file then what is wrong about how I’m doing it now?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer you can use a `.env` file. You can also specify the token on the command line:

```bash
JUPYTER_TOKEN=my_secret_token docker-compose up
```

Comment: Why can’t I specify it in the compose file?

Comment: My understanding is that the environment variables specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file are passed into the _launched container_. However, they are not available to `command`. So, for example, if you evaluated `JUPYTER_TOKEN` from inside your Jupyter Notebook you'd find that the value from the `docker-compose.yml` would be returned.