# Next.js Dynamic Dockerize Process

Tags: docker, next.js

I have a Next.js project. I wanna dynamic build of this project.

An example Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine as build-stage

ARG BACKEND_URL
ENV BACKEND_URL=$BACKEND_URL

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run build

FROM node:alpine as production-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app /app

WORKDIR /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

I wanna build project without env variables;

```bash
docker build -t my-app .
```

and finally I want to run it by giving env variables;

```bash
docker run --env BACKEND_URL=<BACKEND_URL> -p 3000:3000 my-app
```

I couldn't find a way to do it dynamically. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Stick to your Dockerfile and run this command below

```
docker run -e BACKEND_URL="<BACKEND_URL>" -p 3000:3000 my-app
```

Or you modify Dockerfile to build the project without relying on env variables during build time. Instead, set the env variable during runtime.

```
# Build stage
FROM node:alpine as build-stage

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm run build

# Production stage
FROM node:alpine as production-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app /app

WORKDIR /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

Build your Docker image without passing any environment variables during the build process.

```
docker build -t my-app .
```

Run your Docker container and pass the required env during runtime

```
docker run --env "BACKEND_URL=<BACKEND_URL>" -p 3000:3000 my-app
```

This command runs the container with the specified backend URL as the env variable `BACKEND_URL`, without the need to define it in the Dockerfile. This approach allows for dynamic configuration during runtime without any modification to the Dockerfile.

Another method is using the `--env-file` flag is another convenient way to manage environment variables for Docker containers.

To implement this method, create an `env.list` file containing the desired environment variables, such as:

```
BACKEND_URL=https://blahblah.com/api
```

Use the --env-file flag when running your Docker container:

```
docker run --env-file env.list -p 3000:3000 my-app
```

you can also checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried both ways but it does not work. BACKEND_URL remains undefined as if I never defined env.

Comment: @gokhangunduz you can try using the the --env-file or you quote the variable while running the container